# Do I need to change the values for capacitors and inductors in antenna circuit if changing the type of the antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, zigbee

I am designing my first Zigbee board based on samples on the TI website for cc2530. In their sample they are aiming for long range antennas and I am only interested into short range so decided to go with on-board antenna.

[image]

What is the recommendations regarding choosing the capacitor values and the inductance values on the antenna circuit? Or is this circuit only suitable for the type of antennas chosen by the sample circuit designers?

[image]

Comment: If you're changing the impedance of the antenna, then you need to change the matching circuit. Changing the type of the antenna may or may not change the impedance.

Comment: no offense, but this and your previous question say: "In dire need of at least RF transmission line theory before designing an RF system"; in fact, you'd even need antenna design knowledge to just substitute your antenna. So, you're *not* doing what you've been recommended in the previous question: sticking to your reference design.

Comment: You'll probably have to tweak them, anyways, a bit using a network analyzer – unless you have a board manufacturer that guarantees controlled impedance for the traces. This is a *matching circuit* (really, look that up), and your board traces must be transmission lines with a sensible characteristic impedance.